# How to determine OpenCV version

Tags: c++, opencv, version

How to determine which version of OpenCV I have installed?

*I am most interested in knowing a way of doing it programatically (and cross-platform)*, but I can't even find a way to determine the installed version from outside the code.

I'm working with C++03, on Fedora.

Comment: How to do it in C ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can check the `CV_VERSION` macro.

Comment: In which header is `CV_VERSION` defined?

Comment: @Ray opencv2/core/version.hpp

Answer (score 21):

If you also want to get build information, you can use this code:

```
    printf("OpenCV: %s", cv::getBuildInformation().c_str());
```

Answer (score 19):

You can check the following macro variables:

```
CV_MAJOR_VERSION
CV_MINOR_VERSION
```

Answer (score 14):

The version string is located in:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp

```
Top of version.hpp, below the BSD license:
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR    3
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR    2
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 0
```

Comment: This is the only way that i've found so far to check the version of the source code that i had.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to enhance one of the answers using version.hpp defines.

Please notice the potential problem with that solution:

v. 2.4.13.6 defines:

```
#define CV_VERSION_EPOCH 2
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR 4
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR 13
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 6
#if CV_VERSION_REVISION
#  define CV_VERSION    CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_EPOCH) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_MAJOR) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_MINOR) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_REVISION)
#else
#  define CV_VERSION        CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_EPOCH) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_MAJOR) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_MINOR)
#endif
```

and v. 3.4.2 defines:

```
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR 3
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR 4
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 2
#define CV_VERSION    CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_MAJOR) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_MINOR) "." CVAUX_STR(CV_VERSION_REVISION) CV_VERSION_STATUS
```

As a result, *CV_VERSION_MAJOR* are not comparable. Much safer solution is to parse  *CV_VERSION* and use the first value before a *dot*.

Answer (score 3):

pkg-config --modversion opencv

Answer (score 1):

If you install from svn repository, you can see the exact revision version like that:

```
# in the opencv.svn directory
svn info
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working under Windows and you need to configure Codeblocks or any other IDE (thus,you can not issue any command yet nor compile a program ) you can simply go to the folder of installation of OpenCV and look after the final leters of the libraries in the sub-folder "/lib" .All libraries there are named in a pattern that reflects the major,minor and the revision of the build of OpenCV.For instance if you stumble upon a file named *opencv_ts300.lib* or *opencv_world300.lib* then the major is 3,minor is 0 and revision is 0.

(Note: it's likely that this method fails I mean when these informations do not comply with the real version but this will be maybe with the revision but unlikely with the major)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are mainly three ways:

- Determine through `C++` code:-
  Put these lines in your code:

```
   std::cout << cv::getVersionMajor() << std::endl;
   std::cout << cv::getVersionMinor() << std::endl;
   std::cout << cv::getVersionRevision() << std::endl;
```

All of these functions have `int` return type. On my `Linux` machine, I get

```
4
2
0
```

However, I prefer `getVersionString()` because it prints everything with just one function call and it has `std::string` return type:

```
   std::cout << cv::getVersionString() << std::endl;  // 4.2.0
```

- Determine using `opencv_version` binary, provided by `OpenCV`:-
  For example, on a `Linux` machine, go to the `OpenCV` `bin` directory i.e., mostly, `/usr/local/bin` and run

```bash
./opencv_version
```

On my `Linux` machine, it displays `4.2.0`

- Determine through `version.hpp` file:-
  `OpenCV` specifies the version in `version.hpp` header file through three macros, `CV_VERSION_MAJOR`, `CV_VERSION_MINOR`, and `CV_VERSION_REVISION`
  For example, on a Linux machine, go to the `OpenCV` `include` directory i.e., mostly, `/usr/local/include` and read `version.hpp` file:

```bash
$ cd /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core
$ head version.hpp
```