# compile code and "save" library version

Tags: c++

When compiling some code I want to "embed" in the compiled program which library version is used at compile time

## compiling

```
g++ txtbin.cpp -o txtbin `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

## library version

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

How to "embed" the library verison in the program? Every time the user runs the program I want to output the library version of `opencv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to use the `-D` compiler option, which is equivalent to a `#define`:

```
g++ txtbin.cpp -o txtbin `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -DOPENCV_VERSION=`pkg-config --modversion opencv`
```

You might need to contain the version command into `""`.

Then in your code just:

```
std::cout << "OpenCV Version Used: " << OPENCV_VERSION << std::endl;
```

Comment: You probably want a newline or some other space character, and some descriptive text.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add the logic to the code and not as an extra parameter when compiling?

Comment: @clarkk: If OpenCV provides a function to do that, yes. Does it? (That has the added benefit of working with shared libraries, so you probably do want that.)

Comment: @clarkk yes, it does, and this question [becomes a blatant duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11030733/752976).