# Compiling specific lines of code depending on the version of other libraries (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I am writing code to detect Aruco markers in C++ using OpenCV. OpenCV has different ways of calling the Aruco detector in version 4.2.0 as compared to newer versions like 4.7.0.

Is there a way where I can check what version of OpenCV the user has installed on their system and run the specific lines of code. Using a simple if condition does not work as the compiler goes through both the conditions and gives an error for the version that is not available.

```cpp
// For OpenCV 4.7.0 and 4.6.0
if(cv::CV_MINOR_VERSION >= 6){
    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_250);
    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(img, dictionary, corners, markerIDs);
}

// For OpenCV 4.2.0
if(cv::CV_MINOR_VERSION == 2){
    cv::aruco::DetectorParameters detectorParams = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters();
    cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_250);
    cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);
    detector.detectMarkers(img, corners, markerIDs, rejected);
}
```

I believe a pre-processor must be available to do this which I am unaware of.

Since everyone has different versions of OpenCV and due to the different ways of implementing Aruco makers in OpenCV v4.7.0 and v4.2.0.

For example, my code does not compile on a machine using 4.2.0 if I have written the code to be compatible with 4.7.0 (as seen in the error message below) or vice versa.

During compilation the compiler prompts error stating the function is unknown.

```
/home/nova/cnn/test.cpp:32:16: error: ‘ArucoDetector’ is not a member of ‘cv::aruco’
   32 |     cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/nova/cnn/test.cpp:33:5: error: ‘detector’ was not declared in this scope
   33 |     detector.detectMarkers(img, corners, markerIDs, rejected);
```

I want to know if there is a way I can write code that is compatible with both the versions and depending upon the version the user has installed the version specific function is compiled so as to not raise any errors.

As suggested I tried using the `#if` and the `CV_MINOR_VERSION` macros (shown below) while compiling I still get the same error (shown above)

```
// For OpenCV 4.7.0 and 4.6.0
#if(cv::CV_MINOR_VERSION >= 6)
    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_250);
    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(img, dictionary, corners, markerIDs);

// For OpenCV 4.2.0
#else
    cv::aruco::DetectorParameters detectorParams = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters();
    cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_250);
    cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);
    detector.detectMarkers(img, corners, markerIDs, rejected);

#endif
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine OpenCV version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030640/how-to-determine-opencv-version)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this only tells me what version of OpenCV is installed but not how I can use it to compile specific functions or lines of code.

Comment: Well, this is definitely not a runtime check. If you want to support building with different versions, you will need to use the preprocessor (using the macros defined here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/version.hpp)

Answer (score 3):

`CV_VERSION_MINOR` is a macro, and so you can use it in a preprocessor condition.

Something like:

```
#if CV_VERSION_MINOR >= 6
// Code for OpenCV 4.7.0 and 4.6.0
#else
// Code for OpenCV 4.2.0
#endif
```

[Live demo (Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/3rK358Y7e)

You can also use the `CV_VERSION_MAJOR` marco if you need to check the major version.

Comment: This still tries to compile the code for OpenCV 4.2.0 due to which errors are raised.

Comment: You might need to supply a definition with the compiler arguments (e.g. -D CV_VERSION_MINOR=6)

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?q=CV_MAJOR_VERSION -- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?q=CV_VERSION_MAJOR -- that stuff comes with OpenCV headers. no need to "supply" anything. it _is_ supplied by the opencv header.

Comment: @NOVA1323 the marcos are defined in opencv2/core/version.hpp. Though It is probably already included by other opencv headers that you include.

Comment: @NOVA1323 do you have an issue using the `CV_VERSION_MINOR` macro from opencv headers ?

Comment: @wohlstad The issue I am facing is that during compilation errors are raised due to different function calls for different versions which the compiler is not ignoring

Comment: Do you mean that the compiler compiles both the #if block and the #else block ? I don't see how that could happen (assuming no compiler bugs). You can try the golbolt link I posted above. Even if you add some text which clearly cannot compile in the #else block, you will not get a compilation error. If on the other hand the compiler compiles only one of them but the "wrong" one - it could be that you don't have the proper #include from opencv. You can try to add `#include "opencv2/core/version.hpp"` (modify to match your open path) to make sure you have the definition for `CV_VERSION_MINOR`.